# When android system removes existing instances of activities

Tags: android

I'm new to android system and its related things, I want to know when android removes existing instances of activities and their related bundle and data. And also where those instance are stored in android system?

**Edit:** 
Let's say I start an activity and then return to home screen and not back to stopped activity for many hours. How long android will keep all these existing instances and when removes them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android maintains a stack system for storing the activities.

`A -> B -> C`

Your activity could be destroyed upon pressing the home button if the system is constrained and has determined it needs to free some resources.This only occurs if Android terminates the process. Android does not destroy individual activities in response to memory pressure. The documentation states that onDestroy() can be called if:

> This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

You can't determine when it will be destroyed, it's decided by the system when it needs memory so it just kills your app. It's just like `GC` call, you can never determine when it'll be called, it's controlled by the JVM, similarly this is controlled by the kernel.

**Note :** The system can kill your program without calling `onDestroy()` after `onStop()` has been called. Therefore, any cleanup/data persistence code should be in either `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

Comment: I already read android documentation, I almost know an activity life cycle, but the question is how long android will keep all these instances and their related bundle and data??

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so there is no guarantee I always get saved bundle of existing instance and can be destroyed by system, right? And it's possible I save data to bundle and system destroy instance and I lose my data??

Comment: Would you read my previous comment last part, Because I updated while you were answer my question.

Comment: @SaberAmani Yes you'll lose all the data hence the last part in my answer data persistence code should be in either `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wish you move those key comments to your answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: "Your activity could be destroyed upon pressing the home button if the system is constrained and has determined it needs to free some resources" -- that only occurs if Android terminates the process. Android does not destroy individual activities in response to memory pressure.

Comment: @CommonsWare Very true. Added to my answer.

Comment: @SaberAmani If you need to store data permanently, you should use other options than writing the the savedInstanceState() bundle. Your choices include SharedPreferences, database, and file storage. These are all covered in the Android docs.